# badge to the tile in my windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

I want to display a badge to the tile in my windows 8 app.I have tried following code and not getting the badge in the tile.No errors are showing up. I am not getting what the problem is.I am stuck up with this for 2 hours.

```
 var notifications = Windows.UI.Notifications;  
 var badgeType = notifications.BadgeTemplateType.badgeNumber;   
 var badgeXml = notifications.BadgeUpdateManager.getTemplateContent(badgeType);   
 var badgeAttributes = badgeXml.getElementsByTagName("badge");    
 badgeAttributes[0].setAttribute("value", "7");    
 var badgeNotification = new notifications.BadgeNotification(badgeXml);
 notifications.BadgeUpdateManager.createBadgeUpdaterForApplication().update(badgeNotification);
```

**Update**

Hi the above code is working for me in windows8 desktop but when i run that in simulator its not showing the badge text.Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, all of the notifications APIs (toast, tile, badge, and push notifications) do not work in the Windows 8 Simulator. To test and debug, use "Local Machine" as the target.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .I will check with the Local machine.